# How to get cookie data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, browser

I am trying to get the cookie value of my webpage. Currently it shows two listed domains that contain cookies. I am trying to get the second domain's cookies. When I run `document.cookie` it lists the cookie values of my first domain. How can I solve this issue? The second domain is a subdomain of domain one.

Image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you can only access cookies from the current domain. It's for security reasons

Comment: Even if I can select the second domain and view its cookies? It's still not possible?

Comment: Also my second domain is a subdomain of domain one.